# How to Iterate through LinkedList and remove certain words from it in Java

Tags: java, collections, linked-list

Trying to remove some words from a LinkedList. This is the data I used for testing:
`String[] stopwords = {"the","and"};`
`nwl = LinkedList<String>(Arrays.asList(input));`
`String input = "the and of the "`
The result I expect to get is: `[of]` but I am getting: `[the, end, of, the]`.

```
for (Iterator<String> iter = nwl.iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
  String word = iter.next();
    for (int i = 0; i < nwl.size(); i++){
      if(word == stopwords[i]) {
        iter.remove();
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: if you want to remove duplicate use `Set` if you want to **`iterate`** and remove use `Iterator` but first decide your operation

Comment: @FlyingZombie Thanks for your comment. I want to keep duplicates, this is why I don't use `Set`.

Comment: Although initially this question seems to be about string comparison, in a more careful examination it is also about string splitting/collection initialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you compare strings you need to use the `.equals()` method and not the `==` operator. Thus, you need to change `if (word == stopwords[i])` to `if(word.equals(stopwords[i]))`.

Longer version:

Roughly speaking, the `==` operator determines if two variables point at the same object (in our case: whether `word` and `stopwords[i]` point at the same string object). the `.equals()` method determines if two objects are identical (content wise). If your case the program failed to produce the desired output because you had two *different* strings holding the same content. Thus, comparing them via `==` yields `false` whereas comparing them via `.equals()` yields `true.

**EDIT**

Having read the program posted in the link, I found a couple of things: First, the inner for loop's condition had to be changed to `i < stopwords.length`. Second, the `newWordList` object was not initialized correctly. It was new `LinkedList<String>(Arrays.asList(parts))` which means that the `LinkedList` will contain a single String element whose value is `the and of the`, which is not what you want. You want the `LinkedList` to contain *four* string elements as follows:

- element 0: `the`
- element 1: `and`
- element 2: `of`
- element 3: `the`

Thus the initialization need to be changed to `new LinkedList<String>(
Arrays.asList(parts.split(" ")))`. Specifically, `parts.split(" ")` breaks-down the given string (`split`) into separate words returning an array of these words.

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    String[] stopwords = { "the", "and" };
    String parts = "the and of the";
    LinkedList<String> newWordList = new LinkedList<String>(
      Arrays.asList(parts.split(" ")));

    for (Iterator<String> iter = newWordList.iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
        String word = iter.next();
        for (int i = 0; i < stopwords.length; i++) {
            if (word.equals(stopwords[i])) {
                iter.remove();
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(newWordList.toString());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, made the change you suggested but I am still getting the same output. Maybe there is some other mistake in the `for` loop ? The following link contains the test program [link](https://ideone.com/5tpR3d).

Comment: Done replying. please take a look

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer and explanation. Working as expected and it also helped me understand a few things.